# ios load objective c class vs swift class in reflection using objective c

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, reflection

I'm trying to load a class using reflection in objective c and getting different results for a swift class vs an objective c class

What I'm seeing is that using **NSClassFromString**, for an objective c class i need to give as input the **class name** only and for a swift class I need to give as input the **bundle id as prefix as well**

I would like to know why that is and if there's a way to use one code for both platforms that works using the same input

Examples below

e.g.

objective c class - **A**

swift class - **B**

the bundle id of the project is **Test**

```
Class  test1 = NSClassFromString(@"A"); // works

Class  test2 = NSClassFromString(@"Test.A"); // doesn't work

Class  test3 = NSClassFromString(@"B"); // doesn't work

Class  test4 = NSClassFromString(@"Test.B"); // works
```

I tried to do the same thing in swift and got the same problem

```
var  test1 = NSClassFromString("A") as? A.Type // works

var  test2 = NSClassFromString("Test.A") as? A.Type // doesn't work

var  test3 = NSClassFromString("B") as? B.Type // doesn't work

var  test4 = NSClassFromString("Test.B") as? B.Type // works
```

Guy

Comment: So what's the problem to use `A` for ObjC classes and `Test.B` for swift?

Comment: I was wondering if there's API that the same string can work for both objective c and swift classes

Comment: you found the one API already, problem is swift is organised in modules which is a concept that does not exist in objc. But by naming conventions classnames can be found and differentiated if they are objc or swift .. in example with the `.`  & module name in front. Looking for classnames in the other languages space is not encouraged but obviously possible. Because both have their specific bridging mechanism to the other language you run into trouble. Means you could explicit expose a swift class with `@objc(desiredname)` and find it in objc with that name after bridging is properly done.

Answer (score 0):

Swift classes are using namespace and are sorted in modules

So you could extend NSObject and use a helper method

```objectivec
// NSObject+ExposedSwiftClassExtension.h
// make use of @objc exposed swift classes
// with mainBundle name
//
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSObject (ExposedSwiftClassExtension)

/** @name classWithNameAndTryDifferentIfFail:
    gets Class with NSString, if fails try to find in MainBundle
    or with last component, otherwise nil.
    @discussion should find Class with Name in first attempt, if 
    no success tests for "." in objcString and tries without
    preleading module name or within MainBundle as last resort.
    If all three ways fail returns nil.
    @param objcString a NSString as assumed ClassName
    @return Class or nil if not found.
 */
+ (Class _Nullable)classWithNameAndTryDifferentIfFail:(NSString* _Nonnull)objcString;

@end
```

```
// NSObject+ExposedSwiftClassExtension.m
// ExposedSwiftClassExtension,
// make use of @objc exposed swift classes
// but they use namespace and module name
// so this extension makes it convenient
// if module name is bundle name
//
#import "NSObject+ExposedSwiftClassExtension.h"

@implementation NSObject (ExposedSwiftClassExtension)
+(Class)classWithNameAndTryDifferentIfFail:(NSString*)objcString {
    Class desiredClass = NSClassFromString(objcString);
    if (desiredClass!=nil) return desiredClass;
    NSString *classname = nil;
    if ([objcString containsString:@"."]) {
        // contains "." means you assume module but try without here.
        classname = [objcString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."].lastObject;
    } else {
        // last resort, try with BundleName
        NSString *bundleName = NSBundle.mainBundle.infoDictionary[@"CFBundleName"];
        if (bundleName) {
            classname = [bundleName stringByAppendingFormat:@".%@",objcString];
        }
    }
    // if classname is still nil here should return nil anyway.
    return classname ? NSClassFromString(classname) : nil;
}
@end
```

Then use `Class test2 = [NSObject classWithNameAndTryDifferentIfFail:@"Test.A"];`

PS: for objc beginners..
As you can see in code ClassName clashes are done very easily, It is always nice when Classnames are unique and
"ExposedSwiftClassExtension" could be changed to anything different if it is confusing why i choose that name.. It was meant as reminder that un-exposed swift classes can not be found from Objective-C. The Extension could have been written in Swift but would make the use in ObjC more difficult.

Comment: thanks, from reading up on it, it sounds like apple implemented objective c and swift classes differently so swift is created from a different string than. objective c. That was my question

Comment: yes. ObjC uses strings that makes it so flexible, which is why `NSClassFromString` is existing and useful. Swift in that sense is different, so function names need to be explicit exposed to ObjC but offers similar functions to fulfil similar work. Bridging ObjC 2 Swift is a half automated process by naming conventions, bridging Swift 2 ObjC is done explicit with marking functions and/or classes with @objc in front. Its easier to mark swift @objc and use a single declaration in objc that can be bridged to swift to use it in both then the other way around or declare it twice..